# How to write a method to remove non alphanumerics in a string and display it in a list

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, split

method to remove non alphanumerics in a string and display it in a list.

```
public static list<string> s(){
    String stg = 'ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL';  
    List<String> lst = stg.split(',');
    System.debug('test'+lst);
}
```

Comment: Please do not convert your question content to reflect a different question. That destroys the validity of answers. Instead, post a new question. I've rolled back the changes.

Comment: May be that is not helpful to me david.By making it as duplicate am loosing -3 points.

Comment: That is incorrect. Three users down voted your question. Down votes are separate from duplicate flags. Reading How to Ask in the Help Center can help construct questions that don't attract down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regular expressions here

[split](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) accepts regex strings as well.
in current case regex to split string by all non-alphnumerics is `[^\\w\\s]+`

you can try this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/4BVwjz/2)

Explanations to it:

- Match a single character not present in the list below [^\w\s]+
- +Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- \s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

---

```
String stg = 'ABC, DEF, a*b- Cd=*OB=*34g';  
List<String> lst = stg.split('[^\\w\\s]+');
System.debug(lst);
```

result is

> DEBUG|(ABC, DEF, a, b, Cd, OB, 34g)